# What's the difference among 送る, 乗せる and 連れていく

Tags: word-choice, nuances, verbs

They are all translated as "escort/take someone somewhere". Are there any differences?  Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 3):

- 送る: To escort someone somewhere (and part from him/her after arriving there). Escorting itself is the main goal, and you usually have nothing do to at the destination place.

  > 子どもを学校に送る
  >   友人を駅まで送った (because it was late, and I said goodbye to him and returned home)
- 連れて行く: To take someone somewhere (in order to do something there with him/her).

  > 子どもを動物園に連れて行く
  >   友人を駅に連れて行った (to show him around the station)
- 乗せて行く: to drive someone somewhere (i.e., by car). 乗せる literally means *to mount/load*.

  > 子どもを学校に乗せて行く